# Possible to reduce problem to linear problem?

Tags: linear-programming, discrete-optimization

I've been trying my hand at using the Google OR Tools (GLOP) solver, and I've successfully modeled all needed constraints save for one.

Given an array of rational numbers, p of length n. I want to define a constraint so that

$$
\forall i\in [1,n-2]: f(p_i) + f(p_{i+1}) + f(p_{i+2}) \leq 2
$$

where

$$
    f(x) = \begin{cases}0 & \text{for } x = 0 \\1 & \text{for } x \gt 0 \\\end{cases}
$$

In words: I want to constrain the values of p so that at most two consecutive elements are greater than zero.

Can this problem be reduced to or approximated as a linear problem? And if not, how would you solve it?

```
var solver = Solver.CreateSolver("GLOP");
var p = solver.MakeNumVarArray(n, 0, 1);
```

EDIT: For sake of context, the objective is defined as:

```
var objective = solver.Objective();
for(var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    objective.SetCoefficient(p[i], prices[i]);
objective.SetMaximization();
```

Comment: What is the objective function?

Comment: @user1001001 It's a bit hard (long-winded) to explain the entire case, but the p array is multiplied by an predefined array of coefficients (prices). So it's a matter of maximizing p where the prices are high under several other constraints. It's based on a real world problem of optimizing the production a power plant, but this is just a hobby project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M_i$ be a (small) constant upper bound on $p_i$.  Introduce binary variables $y_i$ and linear constraints:
\begin{align}
y_i + y_{i+1} + y_{i+2} &\le 2 &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,n-2\}$} \\
p_i &\le M_i y_i &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$} \\
\end{align}

Comment: Beautiful. The OR Tools GLOP solver had me puzzled for a bit (it doesn't support MIPs and treats the binary variables as a decimal), but after switching to SCIP, this works beautifully. Thanks!